# Error in do Loop: Expected a right parenthesis in expression at (1)

Tags: fortran, codeblocks

On compiling this code using Code::Blocks 16.0.1 on Windows, the following error is shown

```
a(i) = (1/(delx)^2)-(1/x-1)
                1
Error: Expected a right parenthesis in expression at (1)

b(i) = ((-2/((delx)^2)) - bi*ce)
                   1
Error: Expected a right parenthesis in expression at (1)

c(i) = (1/(delx)^2) + (1/(2*(delx)*(x-1)))
                1
Error: Expected a right parenthesis in expression at (1)
```

On adding `&` at the end of each of the 3 statements, the latter 2 become alright, but the 1st one remains the same

```
program HW0
implicit none
integer, parameter :: nx=101
integer, parameter :: ce = 100
real*8, parameter :: bi = 10.d0
real*8 :: delx
integer :: i
real*8, dimension(nx) :: t, x
real*8, dimension(nx) :: a, b, c, d
i = 1
delx = 1/(nx-1)


a(1) = 0; b(1) = 1; c(1) = 0; d(1) = 0
a(nx) = -(1/(delx))
b(delx) = (1/(delx)) + bi
c(nx) = 0; d(nx) = 0;

do i = 2, (nx - 1)
a(i) = (1/(delx)^2)-(1/x-1)
b(i) = ((-2/((delx)^2)) - bi*ce)
c(i) = (1/(delx)^2) + (1/(2*(delx)*(x-1)))
d(i) = 0
enddo

do i = 2, nx
b(i) = b(i) - c(i-1)*(a(i)/b(i-1)); d(i) = d(i) - d(i-1)*(a(i)/b(i-1))
enddo

t(nx) = d(nx)/b(nx)

do i = (nx-1), 1, -1
t(i) = (d(i) - c(i)*t(i+1))/b(i)
enddo
stop
end program HW0
```

Comment: Please also be careful with "delx = 1/(nx-1)", which is evaluated to 0 (because 1/100 -> 0 as integer division). We can get a correct value as delx = 1.0d0/(nx-1) (or 1.0_dp/... etc etc).

Comment: Oh, slipped my mind. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

^ is not a Fortran operator. You want **.